# Youtube data API v3 not uploading video when created release apk

Tags: android, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api, release-apk

I am using youtube data API v3 to upload videos on youtube. It is working fine, but when we generate a signed apk with release mode. it is not uploading video and I receive null in videoId.
Can anyone guess what can be the issue?

I have tried:
Create Android API Key using the released version of SHA1 key.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

In my android app I had similar problems until I created an oauth client with the sha1 from my release keystore. An api key did not allow me to authenticate.  It could be that the api does not care for the dubug version because you can't upload it to the playstore anyway. not sure.

I used this site to create the oauth client:
[google dev console](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=cloudconsole&ltmpl=api&osid=1&passive=true&continue=https://console.developers.google.com/)

the process is similar to how you make the key.  Good luck

Comment: have u resolved this issue? please share the details